# Calculation for regular time and overtime hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I need help in writing sql query to calculate regular time and over time hours for employees for a period of two weeks.Here is the data in my timesheet table for one of the employees

```
Username      hours     date
JohnSmith     3.75       5/25/2015
JohnSmith     11         5/26/2015
JohnSmith     10.25      5/27/2015
JohnSmith     13         5/28/2015
JohnSmith     13         5/29/2015
JohnSmith     14         5/30/2015
JohnSmith     9          5/31/2015
JohnSmith     12         6/1/2015
JohnSmith     12.5       6/2/2015
```

If hours is > 40 then its added to overtime hours. This sounds simple by I am having really hard time doing this. If I sum hours it adds up everything and the total is more than 80 hours for the 2 weeks. How should I sum it so that when the sum is greater than 40 it should add that to overtime. Please advice.

Comment: I assume that by "Sum is greater than 40" you mean *in the given week*? Please clarify?

Comment: What should the result look like? Also, what database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Given your sample data, if the result you want is something like this:

```
Username    Week    total   Non_overtime    Overtime
JohnSmith   22      65.00   40.00           25.00
JohnSmith   23      33.50   33.50           0.00
```

then a query like this should be close to what you want:

```
select 
    Username
    , datepart(week,date) as Week
    , sum(hours) total
    , case when sum(hours) <= 40 then sum(hours) else 40 end as Non_overtime
    , case when sum(hours)  > 40 then sum(hours) - 40 else 0 end as Overtime
from t 
group by Username, datepart(week, date)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bb2b/1)

I used MS SQL Server syntax, but the only dialect/system specific is the date function used to extract the week.

The query can be improved a lot, but without knowing what result you actually want or what database you use I'll skip that part.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help. This makes sense to me. For some reason datepart is not working for me. It says identifier 'week' does not refer to a column, table or property

Comment: What database and version of it are you using? It's probably a syntax difference.

Comment: Yes 40 hours for a week

Comment: Yes its sql server 2008

Comment: @user2233326 With MSSQL 2008 using `datepart(week, your_date_column)` should work. Note that there should not be any quotes surrounding `week` as it is a keyword that the function expects as a literal. See this SQL Fiddle work a working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bb2b/1